# Android Edittext filter for calc

Tags: android, filter, android-edittext

I'm doing a simple calculator.
How do i make a filter for a `Edittext` to only show numbers and symbols `+-*/`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you use digits, for example:

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/et_name"
android:layout_width="100dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:digits="1234567890-+*/. "
android:maxLength="10" />
```

now only `"1234567890-+*/. "` will be allowed in the `edittext`

Comment: How to make sure that the sign(+ - / *) was only one?

Comment: just set `android:digits=""` to all the chars you want to allow in the edittext

Answer (score 0):

this will filter numbers only, though I would suggest that you make buttons that add the number to a plain text view so the user never has the option to edit the text unless they are using the buttons you make, if all you are doing is making an add,subtract,multiply,divide calculator then it would be a much easier way of doing it

```
 <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="79dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number" >
        <requestFocus />
   </EditText>
```

Comment: How to make sure that the sign(+ - * /) was only one?